# Left join query with EF 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

First, here is the simplified EF model I'm using :

```
public partial class MaterielRoulant : IKeyed<int>
{
    public MaterielRoulant()
    {
        this.RelationsMaterielRoulantEquipement = new List<RelationMaterielRoulantEquipement>();
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<RelationMaterielRoulantEquipement> RelationsMaterielRoulantEquipement
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public partial class RelationMaterielRoulantEquipement : IKeyed<int>
{
    public int EquipementId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int MaterielRoulantId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

public partial class Equipement : IKeyed<int>, IEditable, IArchivable, IAuditable
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public partial class Filiation : IKeyed<int>
{
    public int EquipementFilsId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int EquipementPereId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I have a MaterielRoulan item which is linked to 0 or 1 Equipement. In turn this equipement might have 1 son (another equipement) or not. The SQL query I previously used is :

```
select * from MaterielRoulant mr
left outer join RelationMaterielRoulantEquipement rmre on mr.Id = rmre.MaterielRoulantId
left outer join Equipement e1 on rmre.EquipementId = e1.Id
left outer join Filiation f1 on e1.Id = f1.EquipementPereId
left outer join Equipement e2 on f1.EquipementFilsId = e2.Id
```

So my EF6 translation of this query, which doesn't work, is :

```
var query = DataContext.Set<MaterielRoulant>()
    .Join(DataContext.Set<RelationMaterielRoulantEquipement>().DefaultIfEmpty(), x => x.Id, x => x.MaterielRoulantId, (mr, rmre) => new { mr, rmre })
    .Join(DataContext.Set<Equipement>().DefaultIfEmpty(), x => x.rmre.EquipementId, x => x.Id, (x, e1) => new { x.mr, x.rmre, e1 })
    .Join(DataContext.Set<Filiation>().DefaultIfEmpty(), x => x.e1.Id, e => e.EquipementPereId, (x, f1) => new { x.mr, x.rmre, x.e1, f1 })
    .Join(DataContext.Set<Equipement>().DefaultIfEmpty(), x => x.f1.EquipementFilsId, x => x.Id, (x, e2) => new { x.mr, x.rmre, e2 })
```

When I start SQL Server Profiler, I see that my query is translated like this :

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM     [dbo].[MaterielRoulant] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[EquipementId] AS [EquipementId], [Extent2].[MaterielRoulantId] AS [MaterielRoulantId]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RelationMaterielRoulantEquipement] AS [Extent2] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Join1].[MaterielRoulantId]
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Equipement] AS [Extent3] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join3] ON ([Join1].[EquipementId] = [Join3].[Id]) OR (([Join1].[EquipementId] IS NULL) AND ([Join3].[Id] IS NULL))
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[EquipementFilsId] AS [EquipementFilsId], [Extent4].[EquipementPereId] AS [EquipementPereId]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Filiation] AS [Extent4] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join5] ON ([Join3].[Id] = [Join5].[EquipementPereId]) OR (([Join3].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Join5].[EquipementPereId] IS NULL))
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Equipement] AS [Extent5] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join7] ON ([Join5].[EquipementFilsId] = [Join7].[Id]) OR (([Join5].[EquipementFilsId] IS NULL) AND ([Join7].[Id] IS NULL))
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Where it should be :

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM     [dbo].[MaterielRoulant] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[EquipementId] AS [EquipementId], [Extent2].[MaterielRoulantId] AS [MaterielRoulantId]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RelationMaterielRoulantEquipement] AS [Extent2] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Join1].[MaterielRoulantId]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Equipement] AS [Extent3] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join3] ON ([Join1].[EquipementId] = [Join3].[Id]) OR (([Join1].[EquipementId] IS NULL) AND ([Join3].[Id] IS NULL))
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent4].[EquipementFilsId] AS [EquipementFilsId], [Extent4].[EquipementPereId] AS [EquipementPereId]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Filiation] AS [Extent4] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join5] ON ([Join3].[Id] = [Join5].[EquipementPereId]) OR (([Join3].[Id] IS NULL) AND ([Join5].[EquipementPereId] IS NULL))
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id]
            FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Equipement] AS [Extent5] ON 1 = 1 ) AS [Join7] ON ([Join5].[EquipementFilsId] = [Join7].[Id]) OR (([Join5].[EquipementFilsId] IS NULL) AND ([Join7].[Id] IS NULL))
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Inner join replaced by outer join.

I have tried using GroupJoin, which still give me the wrong answer with a much more complicated query. I would like to keep the lambda writing as it's used everywhere in my application but at this point any working solution would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
var q = 
    from mr in db.MaterielRoulant
    from rmre in db.RelationMaterielRoulantEquipement.Where(x => mr.Id == x.MaterielRoulantId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from e1 in db.Equipement.Where(x => rmre.EquipementId == x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from f1 in db.Filiation.Where(x => e1.Id == x.EquipementPereId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from e2 in db.Equipement.Where(x => f1.EquipementFilsId == x.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {...}
```

For expression syntax it'll look like this (for the first 2 joins)

```
db.MaterielRoulant
   .SelectMany(
      mr => 
         db.RelationMaterielRoulantEquipement
            .Where (x => mr.Id == x.MaterielRoulantId)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
      (mr, rmre) => 
         new  
         {
            mr = mr, 
            rmre = rmre
         }
   )
   .SelectMany(
      temp => 
         db.Equipement
            .Where (x => rmre.EquipementId == x.Id)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
      (temp, e1) =>  
        new  
        {
          mr = temp.mr, 
          rmre = temp.rmre, 
          e1 = e1
       }
   )...
```

Comment: Thanks man it's working fine. But i don't get why I can't have the same result using Lambda Expression...Is lambda a beta feature or something ?

Comment: No, this can be written entirely with lambda expressions but that makes it more complicated and difficult to read. I think ReSharper can translate it for you.

Comment: Yea resharper will get rid of linq and turn it into method chaining.  Just set ur cursor on the from in the line statement and have it convert to a method chain.  I think method chaining is much more professional than linq.

Comment: @BrandonSeydel Just because it looks more complicated and is more difficult to maintain does not make it more professional. (In my opinion)
Especially if you need a tool to create it for you.